# Changed the battery cell, still not charging MSI GL63 8RC

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries, laptop

Recently my laptop (MSI GL63 8RC) battery was dead, so opened the battery (6 cells) and checked the voltage of each pair of cells, it was 3.9 V, 3.9 V, 0 V, so I replaced the 0 V cells with working cells (3.87 V). After installing, the battery percentage was 100% but the laptop won't run on battery and won't charge. Is there anything I can do in the BMS to make it work?

Comment: You need to "log in" and reset the BMS. Most of them are password protected. There are online guides available.

Comment: Even worse than just resetting the bms, some battery chips will permanently brick the battery if the voltage goes out of spec. Check for a blown fuse on the pcb with 4 terminals - dead giveaway. Note that replacing this fuse won’t make it charge again, only discharge.